# extending email confirmation to Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, authlogic

I recently implemented Authlogic to my project for authentication. I followed http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic and had it up and running. Wanting to add email confirmation, I found this and followed it: http://github.com/matthooks/authlogic-activation-tutorial

Now, when I try to sign up I get a method missing 'login=' for User model. The example doesn't mention anything about a login method, nor did I have one before.

Here is my user model: http://pastie.org/693910

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you have the **perishable_token** string column in your users database table.

Authlogic needs this column not only for **reset_perishable_token!** but also for the **find_using_perishable_token** method

Comment: Bingo...figured this out the hard way :|

Comment: Why do people say that? Just say "Thanks!" and move on. He took the time to answer your question, that should be enough to warrant a thanks. :P

Answer (score 3):

Railscasts uses "username"; Matt uses "login".

Change his "login" to "username" and you're done.

Comment: Good catch, that got me passed that problem. Now it creates a user, BUT I'm getting another undefined method `reset_perishable_token!'. Not sure how is...I thought it was a method of authlogic? Thanks.